# OAuth authentication for SPFx solutions

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, oauth

I am challenged  by a SPFx based solution (WebPart as well as Commandbar-Extension). I have a set of APIs which are secured by OAuth. There is a dedicated authentication server, so I can't just use AAD to grab a token, but instead I have to access this authentication server.

So my challenge is: how can I provide a solution for an unknown amount of customers running not known SharePoint-tenants, while using OAuth? Since SPFx is a single-page-application-style solution I will have to provide a return-uri to the authentication server. And this return-uri has to be known by the authentication-server to be validated. But since I don't know who's going to use the application - I would need to allow all return-uris to *.sharepoint.com?

So my question is: there must be someone out there, who had the same problem. How would be a way to solve this challenge?

Comment: how are these unknown users going to authenticate to the authentication server? will they have login credentials? or, are you using client credential flow?

Comment: Currently I'm using a code flow with pkce. I'm using MSAL with "LoginPopup" so the user is prompted to fill in their credentials. But I need to provide a return-uri with in case of MSAL has to be the same host as my sharepoint tenant, because otherwise the browser will prevent communicating from the parent window to the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

You can call third party API protected through Azure Ad using following given approach.

1. Declare permission requests in SharePoint Framework projects

- To request a permission when a SharePoint Framework package is deployed to the App Catalog, add it to the webApiPermissionRequests array in the package-solution.json

```
// package-solution.json
{
  "solution": {
    "name": "sp-fx-aad-http-client-side-solution",
    "id": "dfb230b7-4f61-431f-9b65-a34e83922663",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "User.ReadBasic.All"
      }
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/sp-fx-aad-http.sppkg"
  }
}
```

2. Grant the permission to app from SharePoint admin portal.
3. Use the SharePoint Framework Azure AD HTTP client

- The SharePoint Framework API simplifies the access token acquisition from SharePoint Online and Azure AD. The API uses the token to configure a special instance of the `HttpClient`, known as the `AadHttpClient`, you'll use to submit the request.

4. Use below sample of code to call the third party api.

```
import {
  AadHttpClient,
  HttpClientResponse
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';

// Promises
this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
  .getClient('https://your-endpoint-uri')
  .then((aadClient: AadHttpClient) => {
    /* submit request to endpoint */
  });

// Async/await
const aadClient: AadHttpClient = await this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
  .getClient('https://your-endpoint-uri');

// Promises
const endpoint: string = 'https://your-endpoint-uri/api';
aadClient.get(endpoint, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then((rawResponse: HttpClientResponse) => {
    return rawResponse.json();
  })
  .then((jsonResponse: any) => {
    // work with result
  });

// Async/await
const endpoint: string = 'https://your-endpoint-uri/api';
const rawResponse: HttpClientResponse = await aadClient.get(endpoint, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1);

const responseJson = await rawResponse.json();
return responseJson as any;
```

Reference

- [Call Azure AD secured REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-graph-3rd-party-apis/5-exercise-azure-ad-apis)
- [Call Azure AD secured third-party REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-graph-3rd-party-apis/4-azure-ad-apis)

Comment: Just be aware if this is not an Isolated SPFx app, when you grant Graph API permissions, you're granting it for *all* apps, including the potential of user inserted JS on a page that calls the Graph API. So take care when granting an elevated right (such as User.ReadWrite.All). Usually for those solutions I'll have an Az Function as a middle tier where the Function has the appropriate rights, and lock the Function to be called only by the particular SPFx app.

Comment: @rajat: my API is *not* protected by AAD but instead I have my "own" authentication server which implements the OAuth protocol.

But interesseting question: how is for example AAD dealing with this? I mean, I can supply any sharepoint site as a valid return-uri - how are they dealing with this? Do they just allow any uri as the return-uri?

Comment: Provide root url of SharePoint in return uri.

Comment: @RajatSahani: I'm already doing this, but this still leads to `https://customera.sharepoint.com` as well as `https://foo.sharepoint.com` and `https://bar.sharepoint.com` ... So I would need to register all possible tenants.

Just if we would consider I would be using AAD to secure my API access ... I would run into the same problem. And I can't use `https://*.sharepoint.com` as wildcards are not allowed in the return-uri in the app-registration.